# jruby logging how to set package name

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging, package, jruby

When I look in the log under Jboss AS 7.01 using a jruby 1.6.2 rails 3.09 application, I see a message like

16:31:24,259 INFO  [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/apollo]] (http-0.0.0.0-0.0.0.0-8180-32)   Processing by SessionsContro
ller#new as HTML

How can I change "org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase" to something more appropiate to my needs. Background is that I want to define some Packagenames in the jboss logging sections with different logger-handlers per packagename. So I need a packagename of my own application and not of org.apache.
In general : how can I influence exept of the message what has to be logged.

Thanks in advance

Erhard

Answer (score -1):

setup an alternate logging mechanism e.g. if say you're using SLF4J, add these to *web.xml* :

```
<context-param>
  <param-name>jruby.rack.logging</param-name>
  <param-value>slf4j</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
  <param-name>jruby.rack.logging.name</param-name>
  <param-value>apollo-rails-app</param-value>
</context-param>
```

**log4j** is supported as well